# Passing class variables into class methods

Tags: python, class, class-method

How do I pass class variables into class methods? I wrote a program to  recursively swap every second character of a string.

Since I could not pass self.inputstring as arguments I decided to use a nested function.

Is there a better solution? Is it possible to use class variables as arguments?

```
class Swap(object):

def __init__(self, astring):

    self.acc = ""
    self.count = 1

    self.inputstring = astring
    self.checkstring = astring

def swap2(self):

    string = self.inputstring

    def swaphelper(string):

        if len(string) == 2:
            self.acc = self.acc + string[1] + string[0]
            self.count = self.count + 2
        if len(self.checkstring) == len(self.acc):
            return self.acc

        if len(self.checkstring) != len(self.acc):
            return swaphelper(self.inputstring[self.count-1:self.count+1])

    return swaphelper(string)


c = Swap("I'm a string")

d = c.swap2()
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: In the __init__ method, you can pass the variables that you want to work with as parameters

Comment: Why does the `Swap` class even exist? What do you need it for that cannot be done by a function?

Comment: For learning purposes I simply tried to have a class instead of just a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can access class instance variables inside your instance methods like so.

```
class Swap(object):
    def __init__(self, astring):
        self.inputstring = astring


    def swap(self):
        s = self.inputstring
```

Comment: Thanks, that means it is not possible to use self.inputstring as a variable for the class method swap. In general the parameters in the init method can't be used for class methods. Is my perception true on this?